# Why does startAnimation() not working?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I write code to access Flicker API. The code work fine. When I use animation on Image button, It shows the result of Flicker without executing the animation. However, if I execute only the animation without getting result from Flicker it will work. So, if I write the animation method and Flicker method, it will execute only Flicker

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.vanish);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);

    ImageButton boat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.GoBoat);
    ImageButton car = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.GoCar);
    ImageButton airPlane = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.GoPlane);
    ImageButton train = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.GoTrain);

    boat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Boat.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           v.startAnimation(animation);
             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Car.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    airPlane.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AirPlane.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    train.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Train.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe add an animation listener, and only trigger the startActivity on the onAnimationEnd(..)

Comment: this is happening because your immediately launching a new Intent when the button is clicked, try adding a an AnimationListener and running the new Intent code in onAnimationEnd

Comment: it works now thank you very much